# How do certain apps Authorize without connected apps? Heroku connect, Force CLI etc

Tags: rest-api, oauth2, heroku-connect

I am pretty new to OAuth for public products, i am confused on how Public products do an OAuth to salesforce which do not have a connected App. I understand for any successful authorization we need to have a connected app but for products like Heroku connect, force cli there is no connected app created in a org and when i Authorize connection is successful without a connected app?? i am sorry if i am missing something basic but i am confused on how this can happen.

Attaching screenshot of the user login where we can heroku connect and CLI login happens, but where is the connected app??[image]

Comment: Connected app does not need to be present in the org. If you have ever build managed packages your connected app can be in the Dev org and never installed in the customer org. SF probably has some backend system for these we'll know public apps???

Answer (score 2):

Any product that authenticates to Salesforce via OAuth must have a connected app defined. However, in order for a connected app to appear in your list of Connected Apps in the Setup menu, it must be installed as part of a managed package. The reason that you see some Salesforce products (e.g. Salesforce1, Dataloader, etc)  listed in your org is that their connected apps are part of a [managed package that Salesforce automatically installs to your org](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/connected_app_manage.htm). Heroku Connect and the Force.com CLI don't appear in the list because they're not part of the automatically-installed package, and they don't have their own managed packages.

Comment: So if i understand correctly for some reason Salesforce1, Dataloader etc.. are part of managed package but Heroku connect and Force.com CLI are not part managed package but super package that gets authorised even without a connected app. How do we know what app requires connection and what doesn't? How do i see the list if connected apps which dont have a managed package. This creates a question on secuirty of salesforce itself rite? How can i be sure that salesforce is having access to 'X' number of whitelisted apps only. Is the list bigger? Herokuconnect was something i saw from the list..

Comment: any where i can see the list of apps that doesn't need a connection?